# Setup of spring-boot application with JMS, Artemis and JGroups with jdbc_ping

Tags: spring-boot, spring-jms, activemq-artemis, jgroups

I have setup an Artemis HA-Custer example locally on my computer to learn how it's basically working. Now I want to prepare it to be pushed in a kubernetes cluster. Therefore I want to change the way of the initial membership discovery for the broker nodes, so I can use it in cloud, too. I want to use JMS and JGroups with "jdbc_ping". Actually I am not sure, if I am doing it right, so maybe you can tell me if not.

So far the brokers have successfully put their infos in the db-table and are apparently connected. When I try the following connectionFactory from my java application, it starts without errors and connects with the brokers. But in some points I am not sure, if it acts correctly.

```
@Bean
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    TransportConfiguration transportConfiguration = new TransportConfiguration(NettyConnectorFactory.class.getName());

    ConnectionFactory cf = ActiveMQJMSClient.createConnectionFactoryWithHA(JMSFactoryType.CF, transportConfiguration);
    return cf;
}
```

So the single point of question is now, how to setup the connectionFactory for the use of JGroups correctly.

**UPDATE:**

```
INFO 24528 --- [enerContainer-1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : JMS message listener invoker needs to establish shared Connection

ERROR 24528 --- [enerContainer-1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'TestA' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=0, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: Failed to create session factory; nested exception is ActiveMQInternalErrorException[errorType=INTERNAL_ERROR message=AMQ219004: Failed to initialise session factory]
```

Answer (score 0):

The [ActiveMQ Artemis documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/using-jms.html) covers this:

> Lastly, the `jgroups` scheme is supported which provides an alternative to the `udp` scheme for server discovery. The URL pattern is either `jgroups://channelName?file=jgroups-xml-conf-filename` where `jgroups-xml-conf-filename` refers to an XML file on the classpath that contains the JGroups configuration or it can be `jgroups://channelName?properties=some-jgroups-properties`. In both instance the `channelName` is the name given to the jgroups channel created.

In your code you can do something like this:

```java
@Bean
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    return new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("jgroups://channelName?file=jgroups-xml-conf-filename");
}
```

In your case the client will need access to the same database that the broker's are using in order to use that information for discovery.

Comment: I get following error messages, after I start the application: `"DefaultMessageListenerContainer : JMS message listener invoker needs to establish shared Connection`" and "`Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'TestB' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=0, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: Failed to create session factory; nested exception is ActiveMQInternalErrorException[errorType=INTERNAL_ERROR message=AMQ219004: Failed to initialise session factory]"`.

Comment: What I think about my way from the post is, that it's advantage might be, that you can adapt it more easily, e.g. you want to do a jgroups kube_ping instead of jdbc_ping. So you don't need to change the file in the classpath. But I am not sure, if it is an adequate way of connecting.

Comment: Is there a stack-trace with that error message? What version of ActiveMQ Artemis are you using? Are you sure your JGroups config file is on the classpath?

Comment: I am using version **apache-artemis-2.11.0**. There is no stacktrace, only INFO and ERROR messages. I will put them for visualization again in my post. Actually the config file is on the classpath and I even moved it a bit in the folders to check if there is a difference, but it's not. Also if I remove it from the project, there are the same logs. Maybe it can't handle the "jgroups://"-part of the url?